# Can I create a world of stationary planets?

Tags: planets, solar-system, modified-gravity

I have created this massive world composed of 15+ planets, all elevated in space, surrounded by stars and countless other uninhabited/desolate planets. Is this even possible? Do I have to create a center of gravity for them to rotate around, or can they just sit in place, each with its own center of gravity, with stars circling each planet? Also, would space travel still work in this system?

Comment: In space there is no truly "stationary", it all depends on what's your frame of reference. But on its face I don't think this would work with the stars orbiting the planets. As a very simplified explanation: the less massive object always moves around the more massive object. Stars are way more massive than planets, so they will not be orbiting a planet anytime soon.

Comment: What do you mean "elevated in space"?

Comment: You can have whatever world you can describe well enough for your reader to understand well enough to know how things are experienced by the characters and what the constraints on the characters' actions are. Physics is optional.

Comment: With magic you can do whatever you want, without it you're a little bit more limited.

Comment: Is there a reason you want them to be stationary to each other? (eg consistent travel times) Are you asking how to make this work under normal physics, or are you asking what physics would look like in this universe for this setup to be natural?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. As it is worded, with the [tag:modified-gravity], it requires more information. Can the planets remain stationary with stars orbiting them? Unless the modified gravity is defined, the answer defaults to, "yes, do whatever you want" - the Q needs more details.

Comment: Some xianxia novels kind of do this. Also, on RoyalRoad, ["Dungeon Planet: The Healer Always Leaves Alive"](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/68872/dungeon-planet-the-healer-always-leaves-alive), where planets that ascend (a "system apocalypse") are added to some static spiral of planets. The key is not to care about logic and physics and to just say "it is so" (and so it was). You are god. This kind of choice won't make or break your story.

Comment: As an example: the "World Of Tiers" series by Philip José Farmer presumes some physics that make no sense scientifically but work in a fantasy setting. There is also the realm of "science fantasy", SF tropes and STFnal rigor from a few premises that conflict more strongly with our universe than the accepted SF plot elements such as FTL; I d cite Yoon Ha Lee's _Ninefox Gambit_ as an excellent example though it helps if you know a bit about the mythos it is referencing.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, but it's likely a moot point. (a) Please note that you're allowed one and only one question. Asking multiple questions is literally a reason to close questions. (b) All things in space are in motion. Therefore stationary objects are only stationary in relation to something else - but they're still in motion. (c) Is is possible to have a star orbit a planet? Maybe a small dwarf star, but otherwise no. A planet with sufficient mass to allow a star to orbit it would collapse into a star or a black hole. (d) Does this matter? That depends on how realistic you want to be.

Answer (score 11):

If you start with a system of n masses $m_1, m_2,...,m_n$ placed at arbitrary positions in space with null initial velocity, and let gravity as we know it do its job, you will invariably get motion, as every mass will start moving toward the center of mass of the system. If you add an initial velocity, gravity will add a velocity to the initial vector.

The only way to keep all the bodies stationary is to have some force which counteract gravity.

Comment: The OP does have `modified-gravity` as a tag.

Comment: @jdunlop yeah but the level of handwaving required for OPs question of true stationarity is still immense

Answer (score 5):

**No**

Unless, as other posts said, you change the laws of physics for it to work in your universe but if you are doing that you needn't ask the question!

First of all, there is no "stationary" in space. It's impossible to tell whether something is moving or how fast it's moving because there is no fixed point to compare it to. The best you can hope for is the planets are stationary *relative to each other*, or relative to some other fixed point (centre of the galaxy or something)

But even if you establish that - because of their gravity - the planets will all be attracted to each other, so they will all fall in together into one big ball of mass.

Orbiting isn't just a quirk of our solar system - it's what's keeping all of the planets from just falling into the Sun. Orbiting *is* a form of falling, just that the object is also moving sideways so fast that it keeps "missing" the Sun, and ends up just going around it. If it wasn't for this sideways speed, it would just fall straight into the Sun.

Comment: If I dictate Rome or Mecca or Alpha Centauri B as the frame of reference, everything gets complicated, but the center doesn't move. Just math will get so complicated you want to die.

Answer (score 2):

## If you have enough energy you can do whatever you want.

Ramming a bunch of planets together, surrounding them with stars and planets, and hoping it works isn't gonna do anything good. They'd all collide. But, with enough energy or magical sci fi gravity tech, you can make them do whatever you want. You just need to have antigravity tech or thrusts on all the planets and stars to keep them in place.

Space travel would work fine, if being harder because the gravity is absurd.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You could also change how "stars" work.  Make them tiny masses that emit huge amounts of energy that they receive from elsewhere, and they can orbit a planet just fine.

Comment: There are cheaper ways to do it. Big lights classically aren't called stars though.

Comment: Mechanically Actuators for Godlike Infinite Causality is the technical term for this

Answer (score 2):

It's your universe, and you can make it work however you like, as long as you're consistent.  If you want to have big planets with small stars orbiting them, you can do that, as long as you don't pretend that it is *our* universe.

I've seen PC games that purport to be set in our universe, with multiple stars and planets, and every time the developers make some choice compromising established real-world astronomical facts, like black holes with no accretion disks, or planets in fixed locations relative to one another and their star, or even just discoveries made after the game was written, the players start asking when it is going to be fixed.

However, if you include things that are just outright impossible in our universe and call it magic or the laws of the universe or something like that, as long as you're consistent, people will just accept it, with all the advantages and disadvantages that come with it.

So, if the laws of the real universe don't suit you, make up your own.  Disbelief is easy to suspend as long as it's consistent.

Answer (score 1):

[If I remember correctly] any system of mass would have it's own center of gravity. So what you could have is a ring of (evenly sized and spaced) planets rotating around an empty centerpoint. [I'm not that well versed on astrophysics so no guarantees]

From their in-system perspective each planet would be completely stationary and if the surrounding nearby universe is a homogenous nebula or somewhat devoid of stars/things nobody would be any wiser either (until the development of super-powerful telescopes, but given the lack of a starting point it's plausible for those to never be developed)

In such a system Space travel would work more or less similarily to our current solar system, except that you'd have the next planet MUCH closer by

Comment: This is kind of what I was thinking as a solution. But how would an empty centerpoint work? Wouldn't I have to have a star or an enormous planet at its center?

Comment: @bookloverKM that's where I'm unsure but if all the planets are close enough I believe not as long as they are (near perfectly) of the same mass (or the mass is distributed symmetrically within the ring). Over time comets, debris and so on would naturally gather at that centerpoint but in the early days it could reasonably be empty

Answer (score 1):

**Use something much heavier**

As long as there is another celestial object much heavier than the worlds, these worlds can maintain their relative constellation for a long duration without any fantasy physics or science (for certain layouts, such as having the worlds in the same orbital ring).

For example, you could use a black hole for the system to rotate around, with the planets tidally locked to it. An intermediate to high-mass black hole would overwhelm the gravity between the planets, and even between planets and stars. The other planets would look the same from the perspective of one of them except for a brief period of time where the black hole would 'lense' a planet that is on the opposite side of it.

Having stars rotate around your planets to create a normal day-night cycle isn't possible in this type of system if they're like the ones in our galaxy. You could place one or more stars in a higher or lower orbit, but you get very strange light cycles, with some parts in perpetual darkness.

You could create much smaller (sub-moon-mass) 'stars' that rotate around the planets, and such objects could functionally achieve the same thing the Sun does, but you'd need an alternate source for the generated energy (i.e. magic) to explain how a moon-sized object can radiate at 5000 Kelvin for millions of years.

Answer (score 0):

### Just take the right coordinate system and [frame of reference](https://isaacphysics.org/concepts/cp_frame_reference?stage=all)

Stationary is a question of definition. I can describe the whole world with the planet being stationary and me moving in it. Or I describe it with my skull being stationary and the whole world doing crazy backflips as I stand up, lie down, or turn around or get a smack in the back. I can always transform from one to another coordinate system that is a little more sensible. When choosing a problematic frame of reference and core for the coordinate system, the world does not change, but the math for any movements in relation to for example my skull as a frame of reference is much more complicated.

Besides making the mathematicians and physicians bleed from their eyesockets as they gouged out their eyes as they tried to figure out the movement of planets, there's no change to the world overall by taking a horrible coordinate system. A planet describing itself as stationary and the sun running around it is nothing new. There is pretty decent math for describing the planet earth in a geostationary philosophy, but the math for the solar system is horribly complex.

### Multiple bodies with constant distance

Multiple bodies can have constant distances if they follow synchronized paths. One of the simplest solutions would be to have all bodies circle on the same path around a common point at the same speed.

A somewhat more complex solution would take the same orbit and speed but move their centers apart. As long as the speeds, orbits, and centers don't vary, then the objects stay at a constant distance. In such a setup, translating from one planet's coordinate system to another's would be nigh trivial as the planets have a constant vector to one another.

However, you might need to allow rotation independent of the position, because you can not keep all the planets tidally locked to each other, because the positional shift along their orbits would result in seeing slightly shifted images of the other planet depending on the orbital position.

### Timescale is everything

On a timescale that is short enough, our sun is stationary compared to the center of the galaxy. On a timescale that is long enough, it moves around it in a very slow pace. If the timescale that matters is short enough, even a constantly moving system such as the Solar System can be considered stationary for some calculations.

Comment: Just to add to the answer, a civilization like the one in [Dragon's Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon%27s_Egg), which lives one milion faster than us, could easily see the planets around itself as basically stationary

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few issues with your question.

> I have created this massive world composed of 15+ planets,  all
> elevated in space

This is very unlikely, 9 fully formed planets is considered rare.
I guess in theory rogue planets could somehow enter the system and get stuck
in orbit if the conditions were perfect but more than likely it would just collide with an
existing planet in the system or get shot out of the system.

> surrounded by stars and countless other uninhabited/desolate planets

This is definitely impossible, multiple star systems exist but multiple stars surrounding planets is a
very big stretch. The gravitational forces alone would tear the planets apart.

> Do I have to create a center of gravity for them to rotate  around, or
> can they just sit in place, each with its own  center of gravity, with
> stars circling each planet?

Yes, without a center of gravity the system would not be stable, the planets would be constantly drawn towards each other.

Stars circling planets is impossible, for a planet to have enough gravitational pull to force a star into its orbit,
the planet would require more mass than the star and therefore would collapse into a star itself.

The only way this system could exist is if you deleted gravity, in which case the planets/stars would never form.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. It is your "massive world" game.

Example as reference: You could have made a dos level game with just one X in it that simply moves vertically or horizontally. There were games similar to that years ago. People played them.

A follow up question could be "will anyone play your game." Maybe, if you make your game interesting enough. Physics and reality have nothing to do with a lot of games.

Make your game. Put it out for play to a test audience and find out.

I am looking forward to your game even now.

Please post a link to it when you are comfortable with doing that.